# Blackberry: Download and display .jpg image

Tags: blackberry, download, inputstream, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to pull a .jpg image off of a server, and display it as and `EncodedImage` in a `ZoomScreen`. Because this .jpg could be very large I want to save the .jpg to a file and read it from there so i don't have the whole thing sitting in memory.

The problem I'm facing is that Connector.open("http.url.com/file.jpg") is either throwing an `IOException` with the message "Bad Socket Id", or it is throwing a `ClassCastException` when i attempt to open a `FileConnection` to the URL. Here is an example of what i've tried:

```
    try {
        FileConnection fileIn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileURL);
        FileConnection fileOut = (FileConnection)Connector.open(fileDest);

        if(!fileOut.exists())
            fileOut.create();

        InputStream is = fileIn.openInputStream();
        OutputStream os = fileOut.openOutputStream();

        while(fileIn.canRead() && fileOut.canWrite()){
            os.write(is.read());
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();

        fileIn.close();
        fileOut.close();

        EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource(fileDest);

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ZoomScreen(image));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm getting most of this from RIM, but I'm missing something. I know the url is correct because i use the same format when i stream audio from the same server. The exception is being thrown on the first line, when i attempt to connect to the server.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
try {
    HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(fileURL);
    InputStream fileIn = conn.openInputStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    for(int i = fileIn.read(); i > -1; i = fileIn.read()){
        os.write(i);
    }

    byte[] data = os.toByteArray();

    EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0, data.length);

    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new ZoomScreen(image));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope other people will find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void run(){
    try{
        StreamConnection streamC = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url+";deviceside=true");
        InputStream in = streamC.openInputStream();

        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        data = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(in);
        in.close();
            EncodedImage eImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0, data.length);
        }
    catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra input, but what you have here wont work for everything. You are only reading in 4kB, but what if the file is larger than 4kB? Considering that most jpg's aren't very large, yours will work for most cases, but not for everything.